# Motivation for the Huisken monotonicity formula

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, parabolic-pde, mean-curvature-flows

In mean curvature flow one evolves an immersed manifold $F_0: M^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ along it's mean curvature, i.e. one searches for a solution $F:M \times [0,T) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ of the following problem
$$ \frac{\partial F}{\partial t} = H $$
with $F(\cdot,0) = F_0$. 
 
Huisken proved the following famous formula in the study of mean curvature flow
$$ \frac{d}{dt} \int_{M_t} \rho(x,t) d \mu_t = -\int_{M_t} \rho(x,t) \left| H+\frac{1}{2 \tau} F^{\perp} \right|^2 d \mu_t, $$
where $\rho(x,t) = \frac{1}{4 \pi(t_0-t))^{n/2}} \exp \left( - \frac{|x|^2}{4(t_0-t)}\right)$. 
 
I would like to know how Huisken came up with this formula. Where there any previous results for which it was based on?

Comment: If you really want to know how Huisken came up with the formula, I would suggest [asking him](https://www.mfo.de/about-the-institute/staff/prof.-dr.-gerhard-huisken)!

Comment: Huisken made some remarks (p.5 in [here](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.jdg/1214444099))when he introduces the formula. Since MCF is like a heat equation and the integrand is the backward heat kernel, that at least seems make sense to me.